# Getting 'Void not assignable to boolean" error using .find() method

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

The problem comes from this line of code.

```
const t: GridType   = gridDef.find( a => { a.GridName == core.GridStyle; return a; } );
```

The error I'm getting is this

> ERROR in src/app/grid-builder/builder-scratch.ts(255,43): error TS2345: Argument
>    of type '(this: void, a: GridType) => void' is not assignable to parameter of t
>   ype '(this: void, value: GridType, index: number, obj: GridType[]) => boolean'.
>     Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

I'm defining a class to extend to my Angular Components for dynamically creating grids which so far looks like this.

```
export class GridBuilder{
    Settings : GridInit;
    GridData : GridType[];
    Grid     : string    = '';


    constructor() {
        this.Settings.GridStyle = 'SiteGridA';
        this.GridData = GridDefs;
        this.buildGrid( this.Settings, this.GridData );
    }

    buildGrid( core: GridInit, gridData: GridType[] ) {
        const w: number     = multiply( core.Size.Width, core.Size.PixelRatio );
        const h: number     = multiply( core.Size.Height, core.Size.PixelRatio );
        const o: string     = checkOrientation( w, h );
        const c: CellSpecs  = calcCell( o, w );
        const t: GridType   = gridData.find( a => { a.GridName == core.GridStyle; return a; } );

        const cols: string  = calcArea( t.Columns, c );
        const rows: string  = calcArea( t.Rows, c );

        this.Grid = cols + '/' + rows;
    }
}
```

The `GridType[]` being referred to looks like this

```
export interface GridType {
    GridName : string;
    Columns  : GridLine[];
    Rows     : GridLine[];
}

//other interfaces chaining into it
export interface GridLine {
    Names    : LineName[];
    Type     : string;
    CalcType : string;
    CSize    : CellSize;
}

export interface LineName { Name: string; }

export interface CellSize {
    Size?   : number;
    Repeat? : number;
    Min?    : number;
    Max?    : number;
}
```

If we focus back on the `constructor`

```
constructor() {
    this.Settings.GridStyle = 'SiteGridA';
    this.GridData = GridDefs;
    this.buildGrid( this.Settings, this.GridData );
}
```

what I'm trying accomplish is

1. Set parameter to `SiteGridA` to be matched in the `.find()` method to retrive data about the grid.
2. Saving the grid data to a variable that the `.find()` method will search through.
3. Pass variables into function to build grid.

The `GridDefs` is the definitions of the grids which looks pretty much like this

```
    export const GridDefs: GridType[] = [
    {
        GridName : 'SiteGridA',
        Columns  : [
            {
                Names    : [ { Name: 'left-bleed-start' } ],
                Type     : 'normal',
                CalcType : 'divide',
                CSize : { Size: 4 }
            },
            {
                Names    : [ { Name: 'left-bleed-end'}, { Name: 'content-col-start' } ],
                Type     : 'normal',
                CalcType : 'multiply',
                CSize : { Size: 32.5 }
            },
            {
                Names    : [ { Name: 'content-col-end' }, { Name: 'right-bleed-start' } ],
                Type     : 'normal',
                CalcType : 'divide',
                CSize : { Size: 4 }
            },
            {
                Names    : [ { Name: 'right-bleed-end' } ],
                Type     : 'end',
                CalcType : 'none',
                CSize : { Size: null }
            }
        ],
        Rows     : [
            {
                Names    : [ { Name: 'top-bleed-start' } ],
                Type     : 'normal',
                CalcType : 'divide',
                CSize : { Size: 4 }
            },
            {
                Names    : [ { Name: 'top-bleed-end' }, { Name: 'link-row-start' } ],
                Type     : 'normal',
                CalcType : 'multiply',
                CSize : { Size: 2 }
            },
            {
                Names    : [ {Name: 'link-row-end'}, { Name: 'content-row-start' } ],
                Type     : 'normal',
                CalcType : 'none',
                CSize : { Size: 0 }
            },
            {
                Names    : [ { Name: 'content-row-end' }, { Name: 'footer-row-start' } ],
                Type     : 'normal',
                CalcType : 'multiply',
                CSize : { Size: 4}
            },
            {
                Names    : [ { Name: 'footer-row-end' }, { Name: 'bottom-bleed-start' } ],
                Type     : 'normal',
                CalcType : 'divide',
                CSize : { Size: 4 }
            },
            {
                Names    : [ { Name: 'bottom-bleed-end' } ],
                Type     : 'end',
                CalcType : 'none',
                CSize : { Size: null }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        GridName : 'LinkContainerA',
        Columns  : [
            {
                Names    : [ { Name: 'main-link-col-start' } ],
                Type     : 'normal',
                CalcType : 'none',
                CSize : { Size: 0 }
            },
            {
                Names    : [ { Name: 'main-link-col-end' }, { Name: 'feature-link-start' } ],
                Type     : 'normal',
                CalcType : 'percent',
                CSize : { Size: 50 }
            },
            {
                Names    : [ { Name: 'feature-link-end' } ],
                Type     : 'end',
                CalcType : 'none',
                CSize : { Size: null }
            }

        ],
        Rows     : [
            {
                Names    : [ { Name: 'content-row-sart' } ],
                Type     : 'normal',
                CalcType : 'none',
                CSize : { Size: 0 }
            },
            {
                Names    : [ { Name: 'content-row-end' } ],
                Type     : 'end',
                CalcType : 'none',
                CSize : { Size: null }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The `GridName` property is what I'm attempting to match the `GridStyle` parameter in the `Settings` variable to inside the line of code causing the error.

So far I've tried adding `OnInit` to see if maybe loading the grid Data before the constructor kicked in would help. I tried 1 and 3 `=` signs, I tried switching `const` for `let`.  I  really don't know what to do beyond  this.  I've used the `.find()` method in similar instances and haven't had a problem.  How can I fix this?

Comment: find can return null (if any element match). So you can use "union types". That's write "const t: GridType | null=..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After filling all the missing parts, I'm getting different error than the one in your question:

```
const t: GridType   = gridData.find( a => { a.GridName == core.GridStyle; return a; } );

Argument of type '(this: void, a: GridType) => GridType' 
   is not assignable to parameter of type 
     '(value: GridType, index: number, obj: GridType[]) => boolean'.
          Type 'GridType' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Now it says `Type 'GridType' is not assignable to type 'boolean'`. This is because the callback you are passing to `find`

```
{ a.GridName == core.GridStyle; return a; }
```

returns `a` which has `GridType`, and `find` expects a callback that returns `boolean`.

The error in your question says

```
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

That's probably because originally it was written as

```
const t: GridType   = gridData.find( a => { a.GridName == core.GridStyle; } );
```

and when you have code in braces without return statement, it's assumed to return `void`.

If you need to find a grid with particular style, you need to return a result of comparison `a.GridName == code.GridStyle`. You can do that with a simple expression without surrounding braces after `=>`, like this:

```
const t: GridType   = gridData.find( a => a.GridName == core.GridStyle );
```

or with braces and return statement that returns correct (and correctly typed) value, like this:

```
const t: GridType   = gridData.find( a => { return a.GridName == core.GridStyle; } );
```

Comment: great that helped.  and yes I originally did write it that way and added the return afterwards when I seen it wasn't working and realized I forgot to add it, just added it to the wrong place lol.  Thanks for your help